# windows console (cmd.exe or powershell) gets sent sigint on focus?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, sigint

I just realized that my cmd/powershell windows get sent a sigint when they regain focus (via clicking).  On powershell, this clearly displays itself as a red '^C'; on cmd, one can check this by starting e.g. Python; upon focus Python displays a KeyboardInterrupt (which is emitted by Python's sigint handler).

Is it possible to switch off this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I realized this came from an AutoHotKey script.  Oops :)